# How to force Magento Cloud to recompile?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, magento-cloud

After pushing a new code to my Magento Cloud staging environment, the JS stopped working in the backend, I don't run compilation commands out of the Magento Cloud pipelines, but since the deployment, it's not working and the CLI redeploy isn't working to fix it too. Every time I run the command below via Magento CLI, it's very fast, for sure it's not running all the compilation again.

```
magento-cloud redeploy -e staging
```

How could I force the compilation of my entire staging?

Comment: Why are you needing to compile Magento once deployed? The only reason I can think of is dynamically creating a Factory instance using the ObjectManager? There should be no need to do this.

Comment: After pushing a new code, the JS stopped working in the backend, I don't run compilation commands out of the Magento Cloud pipelines, but since the deploy the cli redeploy isn't working to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a generic file in order to run the entire deployment, I usually create a file called `time` in the root folder where I just add the current date, then I push it to the Staging environment.

```
echo $(date) > time
```

Since Magento Cloud won't know about the purpose of this file, the entire compilation process will be triggered.

Comment: I didn' try this, but according to DevDocs https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html#git-commands, you can also push an empty commit:

git commit --allow-empty -m "redeploy" && git push <BRANCH_NAME>